# Replace NiMH batteries with a wall wart power supply

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I have a small device operated by four NiMH batteries in series. The device also has a USB plug with boost-circuit to charge the batteries in the device, without need to remove them.

My goal is to replace the NiMH battery pack and operate the device using a permanent power supply because I do not operate the device mobile.

Is it safe to replace the NiMH battery pack by a 5.5V DC power supply with a (Schottky) diode in series (to prevent the charging circuit to feed back the charging voltage into the power supply) or do I have to consider something else?

Comment: Is your 5.5 V regulated? If not, how high is it unloaded?

Comment: @winny The power supply is regulated to 5.5v, yes

Comment: Then you are probably good to go.

Comment: How many mAh are the cells? What format - AA or ... ? AA Cells under about 1800 mAh can (probably) be trickle charged. Those over that have no Hydrogen recombination chemistry and will die if trickle charged even at extremely low rates.  5.5 V for 4 cells is probably safe. Slightly lower is safer. What is the current rating of the supply? Vmax depends on charge rate. || Removing the cells is viable UNLESS you value the battery operation capability. Ensure there is a large enough capacitor at input.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to keep the NiMH pack, and just leave it on trickle-charge. Using that 5.5 VDC wall-wart and Schottky diode should drop the voltage to that of a fully-charged battery pack, i.e. ~5.4 V, and *reduce the impedance of the power supply*, to handle current surges that might strain the wall-wart. This still leaves the option of mobile use, if desired.